# Flag question vs. close vote vs. both?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

I just gained access to close voting and I noticed that there is some overlap between casting a Close Vote and flagging a question.

If I think a question is a duplicate should I flag it as a duplicate or vote to close it as a duplicate?

Another option might be to both cast a close vote and flag it, but I noticed that the Flag option menu changes after I cast a close vote.  I am still able to flag the post, but there are fewer options to choose from.  Does it make sense for me to flag a post after I cast a close vote? Should I only do this if the question has severe issues?

Comment: I was always under the impression that you should prefer close voting to flagging once you could, and that generally you only use flags for the more serious things like spam/offensive or anything that needs diamond moderator intervention. Don't really see the point in flagging as well as VtCing, although others may disagree.

Comment: Ok understood, however that makes the Marshal badge essentially unattainable.

Comment: Not really - if you ever retract a close vote on a question you can't then vote to close it again, so a flag would be your only recourse there, in addition to the other things that ChrisF mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Welcome to the Guild of Close voters. Feel free to join some of the regulars in the [SO Close vote reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With over 3,000 rep you can't flag as a duplicate any more. You can only vote to close.

As for getting the Marshal badge, there are plenty of other things you can still actually raise flags for:

- spam
- offensive language
- sensitive data in posts
- really (and I mean *really*) low quality posts that should just be removed.
- etc

Comment: Ok thanks...but I still see option to flag as duplicate in my menu.

Comment: @Dan - it'll get converted to a vote.

Comment: Can you add more detail? For example if close or flag goes to the community or to moderators

Comment: Had the same doubt, good answer. +1

Comment: This answer is poor. It is missing too much information. If we can't flag a post if we have over 3K then why is *Flag* an available workflow? (The link is hot) What is the difference in workflows? How do they differ? (I'm interested in ensuring a poor question hits one of the low quality queues, but I can't determine which workflow accomplishes it).

Comment: @jww the question is about flagging duplicate questions once you hit 3000 rep. Your concerns need to be addressed in a separate question.

Comment: I think this is no good mechanism. Even with gold badge, I want to flag sometimes and not instantly close. Effectively, I am unable to flag now. Also, flagging should never instantly close when there is a "close" link next to the "flag" link.