# Why flagging is going to close?

Tags: support

I done the flagging in one question. Then I tried to see the flagging questions
in my profile. But It not having that file. If I mentioning a flag then it it is displaying a vote to close.

Comment: Have you flagged the question and selected 'it should be closed' option? And do you have 'cast close votes' privilege?

Comment: So I can't flag a question it will take as a closing ? Then how can I flag a question?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flag question vs. close vote vs. both?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269743/flag-question-vs-close-vote-vs-both)

Comment: If you flag for closure it's automatically converted to a close vote - the *other* kinds of flags (spam, offensive) still count as flags. Given that you can now vote to close, why would you **want** to flag instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you gain the privilege to vote to close, you cannot cast close flags anymore. You will instead cast close votes.

So what you're seeing is normal, since you have the 3k rep required for the vote to close privilege.

Comment: What is wasted? There are still a lot of things you can flag (answers and comments mainly), and moderator attention flags (the ones where you enter a custom reason). Those will show up in your flagging history.