# What is the difference between Flagging to Close and Voting to Close?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, help-center

What is the difference between flagging that a post should be closed and voting to close a post?

I know that when you reach 3,000 rep, the flag to close automatically [becomes a vote to close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269743/flag-question-vs-close-vote-vs-both), but I don't actually know what the difference between the two is.

There is a review queue for Close Votes, but where do close flags go?

---

As a side-note, it might also be a good idea to add this difference between them to the Help pages.

Comment: I thought this would've been asked/answered somewhere, but I could not find it.

Comment: Flags go there too. But flags (aside from spam/offensive, and comment-flags) can only advise, while (enough) votes actually *do*.

Comment: @Deduplicator Right, so if I flag such a post it goes into the queue, such that people with close votes can go over it and vote for it. It doesn't matter how many flags a post has?

Comment: @AChampion I linked that supposed duplicate in my question, yes. The difference between that is that it asks 'what should I do' and I want to understand what the difference is between the processes. At any rate, that other question didn't answer my question.

Comment: The marked duplicate doesn't actually answer this question. They're not the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Close flags do feed into either the *triage* or *close vote* review queues -- and can be marked as helpful or disputed by either. I don't think close votes feed into triage.

A close vote also, as you might expect, actually makes progress towards closing the post as opposed to simply placing it into one of the queues. Once three people have voted to close, the post is closed.

It's quite common to have flags-to-close marked as helpful, but the post remains open indefinitely. Once you have the close vote privilege at least you can *know* you've helped to close that off-topic junk, and didn't just happen to flag it around the same time someone else decided to close-vote it.

Comment: Is it an explicit action to mark flags as helpful or not in the close queue, or is it done automatically by the system depending on the voting? I also wonder, in what way do close flags feed into triage?

Comment: It's done based on what action takes place in the queue, automatically -- and they feed into it by placing posts flagged into the queue (where they meet other requirements of the queue such as post age and [IIRC] reputation of the poster).

Comment: Note that close votes do also feed into the queue. The major difference between flags and votes is that flags _only_ add the question to the queue, while votes add it to the queue _and_ actively counts towards closure