# Was I wrong to flag this question as off-topic due to typos?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, disputed-flags, typographical-error

I recently made a flag on a python question as a typographical issue, where the user has indentation errors scattered around and a few spelling mistakes.

For some reason though, this was disputed. Is my judgement wrong and this is an OK question? I had assumed this was an easy typo flag.

Question: [IndentationError: unexpected indent in Python in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964133/indentationerror-unexpected-indent-in-python-in-sublime-text)

My mind: That's a typo, read the error, etc. situation. Very confused...

Comment: From the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50964133/timeline) the post was cleared both by triage and first post review queues. Not sure whether it was your flag that pushed to triage

Comment: So everyone looked at it as ok when in comments, it's identified as majorly typo error by me and even the OP?...

Comment: @SurajRao Wouldn't an off-topic flag put it in the close vote queue?

Comment: @AndréKool from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309663/4826457) it can go to either

Comment: @SurajRao Looking at the timeline the question was put in triage the moment it was asked so I doubt it was OP's flag that put it there. Maybe the flag was automaticly disputed after an edit was made. It would be helpfull to know exactly when the flag was posted and disputed.

Comment: It's been closed as dupe but it's still confusing to see my flag going nowhere... If there's a way I can get exact times that flags were raised i'd go look at that and compare to the timeline

Comment: Just standard review queue lossage.  This question was reviewed no less than *three* times.  Triage was "looks ok", FirstPosts was "no action needed".  Close was presumably the one you triggered, but invalidated when it got closed the normal way.  Only "disputed" because it was not for the same reason you picked.  Maybe you give too much credence to the word "disputed", it is not a spanking.  Otherwise a good reminder to deal with the question yourself instead of asking somebody else to do it for you.

Comment: can't deal with the question if i can't lock it or anything heh.

Comment: **normally** this would classify as a typo error and typo errors are *normally* too localised to be of value... but for Python case matters so the typo becomes an common programming problem that many people will run into -> useful question for Stack Overflow. And its now closed as a dupe because of course such a common problem is already asked about before. Me personally: I agree with the flag being declined.

Comment: pretty good view honestly. I do however see that like asking about a curly bracket in a c# method. it's obviously supposed to be there and they haven't done it. Big typo for something so standardised. It's more a pooper when the error is quite self-explanatory where "unexpected indent" means "there is an indentation which is not supposed to be there"; a typo. I'm on the fence basically. I see my view and how it's a Python specific issue. I'm alright if it's in scope though. Imma keep this open for discussion in case anyone wants to fill in.

Comment: and yes I understand the new user discrim. that happens! we don't need a repeat of that certain discussion I think...

Comment: Derp. I say "case matters", I meant "indents matter" of course. Oh if only you could edit comments after 5 minutes... In any case: you are free to stick to your guns. Just don't have high expectations that others agree. Flags and suggested edits are fickle beasts, just do what you think is right and don't get hung up too much over the fact that things don't go the way you expected them to.